# Projecting ArcGIS Tiled Service for Esri-Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, proj, esri-leaflet

I'm following [this example](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/non-mercator-projection.html) from the esri-leaflet docs.

I have an ArcGIS Tiled MapService in `ESRI:102696`. So I'm trying to use Proj4Leaflet to project the service and use it in my application.

I found some proj4defs [here](http://epsg.io/102696) and [here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/nad-1983-stateplane-missouri-east-fips-2401-feet/proj4js/). They do differ slightly, but neither seems to work.

[This](http://maps.stlouisco.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Maps/PublicBase/MapServer) is the Map Service I am trying to use.

I put together a [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/xiloq/1/) example with the code below.

```
  // The two proj4defs I found
  //var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('ESRI:102696', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=35.83333333333334 +lon_0=-90.5 +k=0.999933 +x_0=250000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192  no_defs', {
  var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('ESRI:102696', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=35.83333333333334 +lon_0=-90.5 +k=0.9999333333333333 +x_0=250000 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs', {
    transformation: new L.Transformation(1, 17627100, -1, 19798600),
    resolutions: [
      303.8194444444444,
      217.01388888888889,
      86.80555555555556,
      65.10416666666666,
      43.40277777777778,
      20.833333333333332,
      8.680555555555555,
      4.166666666666666,
      2.083333333333333,
      1.0416666666666665,
      0.5208333333333333
    ]
  });
  // pass crs into map constructor
  var map = new L.Map('map', {
    crs: crs
  }).setView([38.5432816667, -90.2688116667], 5);  L.esri.tiledMapLayer('http://maps.stlouisco.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Maps/PublicBase/MapServer', {
    maxZoom: 10,
    minZoom: 0,
    continuousWorld: true
  }).addTo(map);
```

I'm not sure if the transformation is off or what.

Answer (score 2):

There could be something else going on here as well, but its a problem that the service you are attempting to display has 512 pixel tiles (instead of 256).

Proj4Leaflet has a constructor option for L.Proj.CRS.TMS service providers to let you set tileSize explicitly, but not for L.Proj.CRS.  Since ArcGIS Server is not a 'TMS' tile server it appears that the irregular size tiles chosen for that service are going to be problematic.

https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet#lprojcrstms

Also, i find it a lot more straightforward to set origin using the values exposed by ArcGIS Server than it is to muck about w/ transformations so i'm going to submit a PR to our repo to update the sample.

```
//transformation: new L.Transformation(1, 5120900, -1, 9998100),
origin: [-5120900, 9998100],  //same correct output
```