# EsriLeaflet - Problem with special german projection

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, esri-leaflet, germany

I got a service with EPSG:3068 (http://epsg.io/3068-15949)

My test code to diplay this service on an Leaflet Map with Esri-Leaflet is as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->

            <!-- Load Leaflet from CDN-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
      <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>

      <!-- Load Esri Leaflet from CDN -->
      <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri/1.0.0/esri-leaflet.js"></script>

      <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; }
      </style>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.0.0/proj4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet/0.7.0/src/proj4leaflet.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" />
        <script>
        var crs = new L.Proj.CRS("EPSG:3068", "+proj=cass +lat_0=52.41864827777778 +lon_0=13.62720366666667 +x_0=40000 +y_0=10000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs", {
        origin: [-5469675.610177,5201612.460189],
        resolutions: [
          2.6458386250105836,
          1.3229193125052918,
          0.6614596562526459,
          0.26458386250105836,
          0.13229193125052918,
          0.06614596562526459,
          0.03968757937515875,
          0.013229193125052918
    ]
  });
  var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: crs
  }).setView([52.52261949895406, 13.37957410812372], 5);

  L.esri.tiledMapLayer({
    url: 'http://info.baral.de/arcgis/rest/services/utjsc_de/Grundkarte/MapServer',
    maxZoom: 7,
    minZoom: 0
  }).addTo(map);
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code on jsfiddle:

**Update: New Demo Site: http://s559860669.online.de/EsriLeaflet/index_beta.html**

Nothing happens... expect the JS-Console Warning:
L.esri.TiledMapLayer is using a non-mercator spatial reference. Support may be available through Proj4Leaflet

Comment: Two points: In the fiddle you are not giving your map a height, it should at least display an empty gray box with controls, so add something like `#map{height:360px}`. I noticed on the MapServer that images are not displaying via 'Export Map', they point to 'localhost' instead of the real domain name.

Comment: I deployed my examples on an WebServer: http://s559860669.online.de/EsriLeaflet/ and changed the MapServer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your updated demo code to work, here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/chk1/g8opn5yj/3/
It uses Leaflet 1.0beta and the Proj4Leaflet beta library. It seems to work with the original server URL you provided as well, although, as I said in the comments, the images display broken/404 - not found.

I think the problem was that you zoomed into the map at level 16 right away, which is not a zoom level you specified in the `L.Proj.CRS` resolutions: There are only 11 steps, and the maximum your demo server will display is zoom level 8.

Comment: Perfect! The initial Zoom Level was wrong. Now it´s just perfect at the Demo-URL!

Answer (score 0):

check out my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/126989/21012).

also, you might consider upgrading to Leaflet [1.0.0beta1](http://leafletjs.com/2015/07/15/leaflet-1.0-beta1-released.html) and Esri Leaflet [2.0.0-beta.5](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta.5), as support for custom projections in Leaflet has improved significantly.

Comment: I use the beta releases at the example page http://s559860669.online.de/EsriLeaflet/index_beta.html

Comment: My service has got 256px tiles

Answer (score 0):

It´s a litte bit strange...

My Demo Page at http://s559860669.online.de/EsriLeaflet/index_beta.html shows my map, but only after "a while"...

When you zoomIn the map, there is an error:

```
Invalid LatLng object: (' + lat + ', ' + lng + ')'
```

When you go on zooming an scrolling all of a sudden the tiles are shown.

Sometimes I get an bad gateway error for some tiles.

But maybe my ArcGISServer which is behind a apache reverse proxy isn´t configured well...